# Table going into Repair mode during upgrade

Tags: mysql, innodb, mysql-5.7, upgrade

Recently I was doing an upgrade in production system from MySQL 5.6 to 5.7. there is a particularly large innodb table about 2.5 TB which uses hash partitioning. when I ran mysql_upgrade I noticed that the table went into Repair mode (noticed from show processlist).
is there any way to identify why the table went into repair mode?
I have tried to replicate it using same schema in my local setup, the table doesn't go into repair mode. so is there any way to identify why the table needed repair?

Comment: "Repair mode" may have been triggered by some datatype change.  If the repair is still running, `SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST;` may say which one it is "repairing".

Comment: no we had to revert since it was taking too long. issue is am unable to reproduce the table repair in my local setup.